# Trouble getting UISwipeGestureRecognizer working, never detecting swipes?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to setup a very simple swipe recognizer to change the text inside a text label upon swiping. I tried to follow apple's tutorial [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html), but the swipe is apparently never recognized, because the text never changes. Here is what I did:

First, I dragged a Swipe Gesture Recognizer from my object library to my view, and dropped it on a UIImageView.

Next, I control-click dragged the Swipe Gesture Recognizer from the bottom bar of my view to my ViewController.h file as seen here:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ChordFirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiper;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sampleText;
@end
```

Then I synthesized the *swiper in my .m file, and then defined a method as follows:

```
#import "ChordFirstViewController.h"
@interface ChordFirstViewController ()
@end

@implementation ChordFirstViewController
@synthesize sampleText = _sampleText;
@synthesize swiper = _swiper;

- (IBAction)swiperMethod:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (_swiper.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        _sampleText.text=@"hi";
    }
}

@end
```

However, no matter my swipes, I can never change the text. I added a button with the same _sampleText.text=@"hi" message, and that worked fine, but swiping is a no-go. Can someone please help me identify what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. we can set `direction` to the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` by using direction property.
if you tried like this `_swiper.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft` every time it'l be false because here you are trying to get the direction but it won't work.

For recognizing swipe direction you can add different gestures for different directions.The `direction property` only defines the `allowed directions` that are recognized as swipes, `not the actual direction of a particular swipe`.

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFromLeft)];
[leftRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
[leftRecognizer release];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFromRight)];
[rightRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
[rightRecognizer release];
```

> EDIT:

```
-(void)handleSwipeFromRight{
NSLog(@"swipe from right");
}
```

and

```
-(void)handleSwipeFromLeft{
NSLog(@"swipe from Left");
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. So, instead of having the if statement, I should manually set the direction value, and that way the method only triggers once that direction swipe is detected? Can you please provide me the code for this?

Comment: Yes Exactly you can get like that way.

Comment: @jake9115If you are satisfied with my answer then Accept it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this, I'm almost understanding it! However, I'm not really sure where to put the code you posted. Can you show me how to hook this up to my current code as described in the question? Also, what do these lines do:   [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
[leftRecognizer release];

Comment: @@jake9115:both the gestures which are placed in my code are place in viewDidLoad method and create handleSwipeFromLeft and handleSwipeFromRight methods  which are called based on your swiping directions.

Comment: So awesome, it is working perfectly now, thanks very much for the great help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30200/discussion-between-jake9115-and-sunny)